Dual boot my Asus S15 OLED laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.5 display freeze (black with dots)
I tried dual booting my laptop ASUS VivoBook S 15 OLED S5506MA-MA074W, which has Windows 11 OS.
The steps I followed to dual boot are:

Turned off Bitlocker & Secure Boot.

Shrink my main C: drive to have 100 GB unallocated disk space for Ubuntu installing the Ubuntu 22.04.5 .iso.

Download rufus and put that .iso file to a 8Gb usb flash drive.

Restart and pressed the Shift key to access the UEFI firmware settings and chose the USB as top boot priority.

Then, I pressed at "Try or install Ubuntu".
Note: The display after I pressed that had some red and other colored dots.

After that I went to the Installation type and pressed Install Ubuntu alongside Windows bootloader.

After that I believe it detected the unallocated 100GB because it changed to  Healthy(primary partition) in my Windows Disk Management.




Everything went well. It started the installation, after that I restarted the system and it asked me to remove the USB and press Enter.

I did that, and then I got to the boot menu where it ask you to choose either Ubuntu or Windows.


The problem is when I pressed on Ubuntu it was on a black screen with the same red and other color dots, I waited for 10 minutes and it was still just stuck there.
I do not know whether this is a display issue or something else.

Can you also try 24.04? New versions have better support
